# Forge Viewer - Hiding Root Node via model's Visibility Manager does not update IsolatedNodes property

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are currently consuming utilizing the Forge Viewer in our product and also have an extension that allows us to interact with the Viewer. If we have already isolated some nodes on a loaded model, and then go to hide the entire model, the IsolateNodes property on the model's visibility manager is not updated. It continues to have the ids of the nodes that were previously isolated.

What can i do to have the IsolatedNodes property updated?

FYI....

- The call we make to hide the entire model is as follows: "model.visbilityManager.hide(model.getRootId());"
- The viewer3D.js version we are currently utilizing is v3.3.5

Comment: you can `isolate` or `hide` nodes on the viewer, on your question it seems that you are mixing the 2... can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

With the information from your question, I would say that you haven't fully unloaded the model or need to finish the viewer. One suggestion can be:

```
viewer.tearDown()
viewer.finish()
viewer = null
```